# minio create and list a bucket with curl

Tags: minio

For automation, I want to create some standard buckets in minio, without having a minio client available in the specific environments, as not all machine have the necessary clients installed or maintained.

How would I call "bucket create" with curl? and for testing success how would I list the buckets?

Comment: It is hard to sign the request with curl . So use the sdks or mc client .

Answer (score 1):

If you do not want to use any of MinIO's SDKs or mc, you can take a look at https://czak.pl/2015/09/15/s3-rest-api-with-curl.html

The MinIO team is available on their public slack channel or by email to answer questions 24/7/365.

Comment: It is not the answer.

Answer (score 0):

This is a shell script to list buckets :

```bash
#!/usr/bin/env bash

# Example: ./list-buckets.sh example.url.com:9000 username password bucket-name

if [ -z $1 ]; then
  echo "You have NOT specified a MINIO URL!"
  exit 1
fi

if [ -z $2 ]; then
  echo "You have NOT specified a USERNAME!"
  exit 1
fi

if [ -z $3 ]; then
  echo "You have NOT specified a PASSWORD!"
  exit 1
fi

# User Minio Vars
URL=$1
USERNAME=$2
PASSWORD=$3
MINIO_PATH="/"

# Static Vars
DATE=$(date -R --utc)
CONTENT_TYPE='application/zstd'
SIG_STRING="GET\n\n${CONTENT_TYPE}\n${DATE}\n${MINIO_PATH}"
SIGNATURE=`echo -en ${SIG_STRING} | openssl sha1 -hmac ${PASSWORD} -binary | base64`
PROTOCOL="http"

curl -k -H "Host: $URL" \
    -H "Date: ${DATE}" \
    -H "Content-Type: ${CONTENT_TYPE}" \
    -H "Authorization: AWS ${USERNAME}:${SIGNATURE}" \
    ${PROTOCOL}://$URL${MINIO_PATH}
```

[Derived from the work done by JustinTimperio on Github](https://gist.github.com/JustinTimperio/ae695eef5fda1f1590a685a017bbb5ec)